# How to install node dependency with compiled files only?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, compilation

I have node project with multi-module structure. And written in typescript. When installing the other module as a dependency. The whole directory structure gets copied to `node_modules` directory. But i only want to have the compiled files.

Actual:

```
Module1/
    |-lib/
    |   |-index.js
    |
    |-src/
    |   |-index.ts
    |
    |-node_moodules/
    |   |-Module2/
    |       |-lib/
    |       |   |-index.js
    |       |
    |       |-src/
    |       |   |-index.ts
    |       |
    |       |-node_modules/
    |       |-package.json
    |       |-tsconfig.json
    |
    |
    |-package.json
    |   dependencies: Module2
    |
    |-tsconfig.json

Module2/
    |-lib/
    |   |-index.js
    |
    |-src/
    |   |-index.ts
    |
    |-node_modules/
    |-package.json
    |   main: lib/index.js
    |
    |-tsconfig.json
```

Expected:

```
Module1/
    |-lib/
    |   |-index.js
    |
    |-src/
    |   |-index.ts
    |
    |-node_moodules/
    |   |-Module2/
    |       |-lib/
    |       |   |-index.js
    |       |
    |       |-package.json
    |       |-tsconfig.json
    |
    |
    |-package.json
    |   dependencies: Module2
    |
    |-tsconfig.json

Module2/
    |-lib/
    |   |-index.js
    |
    |-src/
    |   |-index.ts
    |
    |-node_modules/
    |-package.json
    |   main: lib/index.js
    |
    |-tsconfig.json
```

Check the above project structure. When I run `npm install Module2` in `Module1` the whole directory structure of `Module2` gets copied to `node_modules` of `Module1`. How can I disallow this i.e. while installing any dependency only the compiled or specific folders get copied to `node_modules`.

Edit1:

Module2: [package.json](http://myjson.com/g8ij7)

Module1: [package.json](http://myjson.com/1almdv)

Comment: This may be related to the files property in the package.json for Module2. For example. Can you post the package.json for Module2 and Module1?

Comment: @MobiusLSV Please find the package.json file in edit1.

Comment: Have you tried to specifiy the "files" property as a directory? "lib/**/*"?